# Is "Popped up" appropriate in this context?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request, phrasal-verbs

> The masked man started down an aisle of cubicles. As he reached the
> end of it and looked into the cubicle on his right, Lena **popped up**
> from a cubicle behind him and threw a computer screen at him, hitting
> him in the head.

Hi. Can I use "popped up" here to mean she stood up in a cubicle and became visible suddenly? It doesn't seem to be commonly used but I can't find a better alternative. Does it seem OK to you? Thank you.

**Pop up:**
To appear or occur suddenly.

Comment: _Pop up_ is fine as to meaning but, if this is a thriller, it might sound  a bit 'light-hearted'. You know best what the tone of your story is.

Comment: Yes, you can, but it does give light-hearted mood to the sentence which clashes a bit with the violent content. May I recommend "erupted" if it's an explosive motion, "emerged" if it's more sneaky...